# Can I block keychain sync between devices but allow restore on new device

Tags: ios, icloud, keychain

I want to support in new device restore from backup but don't want keychain data to sync between current devices. The kSecAttrSynchronizable attribute cause both of the requirements to behave the same. Any way to do it?